# Как изменить генератор случайных чисел?

Tags: python

Как сделать генератор случайных чисел диапазон символов (`0123456789abcdef`) 32 символа в строке. Чтобы не перегружал оперативку, например:

```
import random, string
listToPrint = set()
while len(listToPrint) < 100000000:
    listToPrint .add(''.join(random.choice("0123456789abcdef") for i in range(32)))
print ('\n'.join(listToPrint))
```

Comment: Задача поставлена? Делайте, разрешаю.

Comment: @Other Извеняюсь за не корректный вопрос в начале.Исправил.Как сделать генератор случайных чисел диапазон символов (0123456789abcdef) 32 символа в строке. Чтобы не перегружал оперативку при например while len(listToPrint) < 10000000000 import random, string
listToPrint = set()
while len(listToPrint) < 100000000:
listToPrint .add(''.join(random.choice("0123456789abcdef") for i in range(32)))
print ('\n'.join(listToPrint))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import randint
length = 32  # длина
number = 100  # количество
values = (hex(randint(0, 16**length-1))[2:].zfill(length) for i in range(number))
for i in values:
    print(i)
```

Случайная строка создаётся здесь:

```
hex(randint(0, 16**length-1))[2:].zfill(length)
```

Мы генерируем случайное число от `0` до `16**length-1`, чтобы в 16сс там было не больше `length` цифр. Переводим число в 16сс методом `hex`. Делаем срез строки со 2-го элемента, т.к. в начале стоит `"0x"`. Так как ведущие нули, если они есть, не пишутся, дополняем нулями слева строку до 32 символов методом `zfill`.

В 4-й строке кода в круглых скобках создаётся т.н. генератор. Он не вычисляет сразу все значения, а лишь задаёт правило как и сколько их нужно вычислять, поэтому память он не забивает. Дальше в цикле мы проходим по генератору и выводим значения. Каждую итерацию вычисляется следующее значение.

Заметьте, что второй раз пройти в цикле по тому же генератору нельзя. Для этого нужно создать новый генератор.

https://ideone.com/BFIIAE

Comment: d0c117ff05d6cb857d8ee548043f17f7L Добовляет L во всех строках. Как это исправить?

Comment: d0c117ff05d6cb857d8ee548043f17f7L Добовляет в конце  L во всех строках. Как это исправить?

Comment: @Дима, перейти на 3-й Питон. Или пишите так https://ideone.com/4FenRq

Comment: Исправил так `values = (hex(randint(0, 16**length-1))[2:][:32].zfill(length) for i in range(number))`

Comment: Спасибо.........

Comment: @Дима. если немного изменить 2-й ответ, можно так https://ideone.com/M7aDWN

Answer (score 1):

```
'%32x' % random.getrandbits(128)
```